# Error converting varchar to numeric (but there's no number)

Tags: oracle, varchar2, numeric-conversion

I have a table with several columns, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE CRM.INFO_ADICIONAL
(
  ID_INFO_ADICIONAL        NUMBER(10)           NOT NULL,
  NOMBRE                   VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)   NOT NULL,
  OBLIGATORIO              NUMBER(1)            NOT NULL,
  TIPO_DATO                VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)     NOT NULL,
  ACTIVO                   NUMBER(1)            NOT NULL,
  ID_TIPO_REQUERIMIENTO    NUMBER(10)           NOT NULL,
  ID_USUARIO_AUDIT         NUMBER(10)           NOT NULL,
  ORDEN                    NUMBER(3)            DEFAULT 1,
  RECHAZO_POR_NO           NUMBER(1),
  ID_TIPO_ARCHIVO_ADJUNTO  NUMBER(10),
  SOLICITAR_EN             VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  ID_CONSULTA              NUMBER(10),
  COMBO_ID                 VARCHAR2(40 BYTE),
  APLICAR_COMO_VENC        NUMBER(1),
  MODIFICABLE              NUMBER(1)            DEFAULT 0,
  ID_AREA_GESTION          NUMBER(10),
  ID_TAREA                 NUMBER(10)
)
```

The **"COMBO_ID"** column is the target. It is defined as VARCHAR, but when I'm trying to insert a row, TOAD displays

> "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: error : error de conversión de carácter a número
>   numérico o de valor"

Or a 'numeric conversion error', in english.

This table have some pre-existing data, and I even found some rows including values at COMBO_ID column, all of them being VARCHAR, i.e.:

> NACION (Nation),  SEXO (Sex), etc

I tried a few simple SELECT statements

```
SELECT
    ID_INFO_ADICIONAL,
    NOMBRE,
    OBLIGATORIO,
    TIPO_DATO,
    ACTIVO,
    ID_TIPO_REQUERIMIENTO,
    ID_USUARIO_AUDIT,
    ORDEN,
    RECHAZO_POR_NO,
    ID_TIPO_ARCHIVO_ADJUNTO,
    SOLICITAR_EN,
    COMBO_ID,
    APLICAR_COMO_VENC,
    ID_CONSULTA,
    MODIFICABLE,
    ID_AREA_GESTION,
    ID_TAREA
INTO
    pRegistro
FROM
    crm.info_adicional
```

where **pRegistro** is declared as

> pRegistro INFO_ADICIONAL%ROWTYPE;

Again, I'm still getting this 'numeric conversion error'.
But, wait, if I hardcode the SELECT value in COMBO_ID column with a NUMBER:

```
SELECT
    --other columns
    123456 COMBO_ID,
    --other columns
INTO
    pRegistro
FROM
    crm.info_adicional
```

It works, what the heck, it's defined as VARCHAR.
If I do the same but harcoding a string, it fails to execute again

Already tried in my DEV environment, and it's working fine.

I'm not a pro in Oracle, but I feel pretty lost.
Could it be that tables get "confused"?
Any clues?

Comment: What is the value for COMBO_ID? In case it is longer than 40 Byte you get also ORA-06502.

Comment: In your last example, shouldn't that be 123456 COMBO_ID?

Comment: Put the message that toad displayed in English. This change could help you more to get a right answer.

Comment: Test query with just a subset of records first to see if it's a data problem, using SELECT TOP 10...

Comment: @GordonBell , you're right, it should be COMBO_ID, I'm chaging it now. Thank you

Comment: @CarlosAndrésGarcía I'll try setting TOAD in English and repplying the English version

Comment: @HugoLisandroPuyol  Try https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ORA-06502. There are many answers with respect ORA-06502

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I already found the answer.

Quoting Oracle Documentation:

> The %ROWTYPE attribute provides a record type that represents a row in a table or view. **Columns in a row and corresponding fields in a record have the same names and datatypes.**

So, basically, the SELECT statement needed to be in the same order as the table columns definition.

In my case, I had a few columns (including COMBO_ID) in a different order.
Tried, re-ordering, and works like a charm.

Thank you all for the support.

Answer (score 0):

That error can also be raised if you try to push a character string that is longer than your VARCHAR2's capacity (40 in your case).

Try to check if all the data you are trying to insert is correct :

```
SELECT
    COMBO_ID
FROM
    crm.info_adicional
ORDER BY length(COMBO_ID) desc;
```

That would also explain why it works fine on your DEV environment which, I suppose, has different data.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that, but I tried with an specific row, containing valid data in that column, like the one I quoted in the post (NATION,SEX). All of them are 'valid' values. Anyway I'll check and let you know

Comment: Okay, already tried, and the value with max length was 17 chars. So, I guess this shouldn't be a problem